# react json schema form not sending empty value key

Tags: react-jsonschema-forms

I am using react json schema form for form creation. I am trying to submit the form. When I am sending the empty value. Key is eliminted from the data. for example
In a form, I have two fields Name and Address.
Input
     name="abc"
     address=""

Output
{
name:abc
}

Required output
{
name:abc,
address:
}

Comment: Your strings should be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: Provide some more info and your code which can show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use defaults.
try

```
{
  "title": "A registration form",
  "description": "A simple form example.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "name",
      "default": ""
    },
    "address": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "address",
      "default": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about when this is a number? Do you have to default to 0, lol?